# Best way to use get_absolute_url by foreign key field

Tags: python, django

**What is the best way to create get_absolute_url function for Comment if I need url like this: "/article_url#comment-id"?**

My models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article-detail', args=[self.url])

class Comment(models.Model):
    related_article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
```

My variants:

1) very simple, but in this case django will fetch all fields of article, it's terrible for views like "latest 10 comments" on main page:

```
u = self.related_article.get_absolute_url()
return ''.join([u, '#comment-', str(self.pk)])
```

2) in this case, function will be independent of Article class changes, but django will fetch pk in first query and url in second query:

```
u = Article.objects.filter(pk=self.related_article_id) \
                              .only('pk') \
                              .get() \
                              .get_absolute_url()
return ''.join([u, '#comment-', str(self.pk)])
```

3) in this case, field 'url' was hardcoded, but django will fetch pk and url in one query:

```
u = Article.objects.filter(pk=self.related_article_id) \
                              .only('url') \
                              .get() \
                              .get_absolute_url()
return ''.join([u, '#comment-', str(self.pk)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are gaining much by storing the **url** in your Article model and providing a **get_absolute_url**, however, you do not need to worry about trying to explicitly support anchor tags in your URL; just make sure that you are setting the id properly in your  tags in the template.

```
# views.py
def article_detail(request, article_id):
    # Proper exception try/except handling excluded:
    article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
    article_comments = Comment.objects.filter(related_article_id=article_id)

    return render_to_response('article_detail.html', {'article': article, 
                                                      'article_comments': article_comments}

# article_detail.html
{% for article_comment in article_comments %}
    <div id='comment-{{article_comment.id}}'>
       {# Comment information here. #}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

If you are interested in hyperlinking a summary list of comments back to the original article where the comment appeared, then you are probably best defining a **get_absolute_url** function for the Comment model as well.

Edit:  Let's say you are showing the 10 latest comments on your main page, where the actual article is not appearing:

```
# views.py
def main(request):
    # Assumes timestamp exists for comments.
    # Note: This query will get EXPENSIVE as the number of comments increases,
    #       and should be replaced with a better design for a production environment.
    latest_article_comments = Comment.objects.all().order_by('creation_date')[:10]

    render_to_response('main.html', {'latest_article_comments': latest_article_comments})


# main.html
{% for article_comment in article_comments %}
    <a href="{% url 'article.views.article_detail' article_comment.related_article.id %}#comment-{{article_comment.id}}">{{article_comment.user_comment}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's not so easy if need to show the comments not on related_article's page. How to resolve comment's url on main page, admin, etc? I use CBV.

Comment: I have edited my original answer in response to your question.

Comment: Django will fetch all fields of article from DB if I will use article_comment.related_article.id. It's terrible for performance.

Comment: Try article_comment.related_article_id...I should have used that to begin with.

Comment: "_id" works good, but I need ".url" for resolve article's absolute_url (look at my model). Maybe resolving by url field, rather than id, is a poor way...